# Disable Wikipedia's link preview when not logged in

Tags: firefox, wikipedia

I'd like to disable Wikipedia's article previews that are shown when hovering over a link:

[image: Wikipedia link preview screenshot]

I know I can disable those when being logged in but most of the time I'm using Wikipedia without being logged in. I also delete my cookies regularly.

I hoped that there would be a Greasemonkey script to disable them but I couldn't find anything relevant on [OpenUserJS](https://openuserjs.org) or [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en).

I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Best place to ask that is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk PS If you get an answer feel free to post as an answer here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-wiki-page-previews/) to disable these previews:

[image: screenshot without add-on]

[image: screenshot with add-on]

All the add-on does is this, which disables the previews:

```
localStorage["mwe-popups-enabled"] = 0;
```

Its source code is [here](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/disable-wiki-previews).

The add-on works for users that aren't logged in to Wikipedia and regularly delete their browser state (e.g., [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), cookies).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a script. Wikipedia gives you the option via a pop-up no matter the browser.
Even not logged in you can turn it off by:

- **Hover over any article link**.
- **On the preview, click on the gear icon in the bottom-right corner**.

[image]

- **Select "Disable" in the pop-up and then "Save"**.

[image]

[Wikipedia:Tools/Navigation popups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Navigation_popups)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works until I restart Firefox (I delete all the cookies when exiting).

Comment: _"This works until I restart Firefox (I delete all the cookies when exiting)"_. That is the whole idea of cookies. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't rely on cookies since, as I stated in the question, I clear them regularly for privacy reasons and as far as I know there's no option in Firefox that would exempt cookies of certain sites from deletion.

Comment: _"I appreciate your answer. I was hoping for a solution that ..."_ This is as good as it gets. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MatthiasBraun I agree, if a user is interested in their privacy then this answer is not a solution. Wiki is enabling this for all users and is another example of unchecked propaganda techniques forcibly bullying users into making them view unwanted stimulus. I know the legal system will be helpless in these situations. But developing much safer browsers are possible - including machine learning (AI) powered ad blocking technology to end this era of nonsense for good.